# Pandas dataframe highlight cell that meets conditions in a row if one column's value is equal to another table's value

Tags: python, pandas, excel

Let's say I have a table1:
column: Name, logic, color

```
['NTM NR AVL Cell Availability [ Planned Downtime Excluded ]', 'negative', 'red']
['NTM NR AVL Cell Availability [ UnPlanned Downtime Excluded ]', 'negative', 'red']
['NTM NR PWR PUSCH Receive Interference Power dBm', 'negative', 'green']
['NTM NR CAP DL Average Cell Throughput Mbps', 'negative', 'red']
['NTM NR CAP UL Average Cell Throughput Mbps', 'negative', 'red']
```

I have another table2 like this:

```
column: Name, val1, val2, val3
'NTM NR AVL Cell Availability [ Planned Downtime Excluded ]', 2, 3, -1
'NTM NR AVL Cell Availability [ UnPlanned Downtime Excluded ]', 5, 6, -4
'NTM NR PWR PUSCH Receive Interference Power dBm', -2, 0 , 1
'NTM NR CAP DL Average Cell Throughput Mbps', 2, 3, 2
'NTM NR CAP UL Average Cell Throughput Mbps', -1, -2, -5
```

I would like to highlight table if the value for each name is follow by table1's logic.
For example the output will be a table be colored like this:

```
'NTM NR AVL Cell Availability [ Planned Downtime Excluded ]', 2, 3, -1(red)
'NTM NR AVL Cell Availability [ UnPlanned Downtime Excluded ]', 5, 6, -4(red)
'NTM NR PWR PUSCH Receive Interference Power dBm', -2(green), 0 , 1
'NTM NR CAP DL Average Cell Throughput Mbps', 2, 3, 2
'NTM NR CAP UL Average Cell Throughput Mbps', -1(red), -2(red), -5(red)
```

Comment: Highlight how/where? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?